# Using launchd for persistent scripts

Tags: macos, launchd, daemon

I have launchd configured to run a script. This works fine for the user who installed it (me), but it relaunches the script every time I log in, while I'd like it to run as long as the computer is on (like a windows service).

Details - 
Location:

/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.pluuserwatcher.osx.test.plist

Contents:

```
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.pluuserwatcher.osx.test</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/max/Projects/PLU/Utils/userwatcher.py</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's in /Library/LaunchDaemons?  The behavior you describe sounds like it's in /Library/LaunchAgents instead.

Comment: Yes, I loaded it with launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.pluuserwatcher.osx.test.plist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you load the launchd item by running `launchctl load ...` as a normal user, it loads it for your user launchd instance (i.e. essentially as a LaunchAgent, so it only runs within your user login sessions.  To load it into the system launchd (as a proper LaunchDaemon), use `sudo launchctl load ...` (or just put it in /Library/LaunchDaemons and reboot).

Comment: Thanks - it appears to work! Unfortunately I can't upvote for lack of reputation points :(

Comment: @MaximKhesin: Great! Since it worked, please mark this as the "accepted" answer (see the instructions [here](http://superuser.com/faq#howtoask)).